# Vue js props are not overriding

Tags: vuejs3

I have three buttons that I trying to customize the color for. However, they are all showing the default color instead of the colors I defined in buttons. Meanwhile, other variable processing is working.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" class="h-full">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Episode 5: Extract Components to Their Own Files</title>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
<style>
@keyframes spinner {
to {transform: rotate(360deg);}
        }
        .is-loading { color: transparent; }
        .is-loading:before {
content: '';
box-sizing: border-box;
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
width: 20px;
height: 20px;
margin-top: -10px;
margin-left: -10px;
border-radius: 50%;
border: 2px solid #ccc;
border-top-color: #000;
animation: spinner .6s linear infinite;
        }
</style>
</head>
<body class="h-full grid place-items-center">
<div id="app">
<app-button :processing="false" :type="primary">Submit</app-button>
<app-button :processing="false" :type="secondary">Submit</app-button>
<app-button :processing="false" :type="muted">Submit</app-button>
</div>
<script>

let AppButton = {
    
    template: `
        <button 
            :class="{
                'border rounded px-5 py-2 disabled:cursor-not-allowed': true,
                'bg-blue-600 hover:bg-blue-700': type === 'primary',
                'bg-purple-200 hover:bg-purple-400': type === 'secondary',
                'bg-gray-200 hover:bg-gray-400': type === 'muted',
                'is-loading': processing
            }" 
            :disabled="processing"
        >
            <slot />
        </button>
    `,
    props: {
        type: {
            type: String,
            default: 'muted'
        },
        processing: {
            type: Boolean,
            default: false
        }
    }
};

let App = {
components: {
'app-button': AppButton
}}

Vue.createApp(App).mount('#app');
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I tried to define in Button-Tag the Type with different class names. But it shows still the 'muted' class.

```
<app-button :processing="false" :type="primary">Submit</app-button>
<app-button :processing="false" :type="secondary">Submit</app-button>
<app-button :processing="false" :type="muted">Submit</app-button>
```

Comment: Did you look at the console output? It should tell you something like *primary is not defined*, which indicates that JS is looking for a variable named `primary`. You put a statement into `type`, not a string. Remove the colon `type="primary"` or add quotes `:type="'primary'"